# How to use Calculated Join in Tableau using 1-M relationship and regex_extract

Tags: regex, join, tableau-api, one-to-many, regex-group

Question 1 - Is Tableau able to use multiple results from from a single line in a REGEXP using the global variable to compare against another table during a Join operation?  If no, question 2 is null.  If yes...

Question 2 - I'm attempting to join two data sources in Tableau using a regexp in a calculated join because the left table has 1 value in each cell (ie. 64826) and the right table has 4 possible matches in each cell (ie. 00000|00000|21678|64826).

The problem is that my regex stops looking after it finds 1 match (the first of 4 values), and the global variable /g has the opposite effect I expected and eliminates all matches.

I've tried calculated joins on the Data Source tab. I've also tried separating those 4 values into their own columns in worksheets using 
`regexp_extract_nth`. In both cases, regex stops looking after the first result. A Left Join seems to work somewhat, while an Outer Join returns nothing.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Event Number],'(\d{5})')
REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([Event Number],'(?!0{5})(\d{5})',1)
```

With these examples, regex would match a NULL with the left table even though 64826 is in the right table. I expect the calculated join to return all possible matches from the right set, so there'd be a match on 21678 and on 64826, duplicating rows in the right table like so...

```
21678 - 00000|00000|21678|64826
64826 - 00000|00000|21678|64826
45245 - 45106|45245|00000|00000
45106 - 45106|45245|00000|00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original expression is just fine, we might want to make sure that we are sending a right command in Tableau, which I'm not so sure, maybe let's try an expression similar to:

```
\b([^0]....)\b
```

even just for testing, then maybe let's modify our commands to:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT([Event Number], '\b([^0]....)\b')
```

or:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([Event Number], '\b([^0]....)\b', 1)
```

to see what happens. I'm assuming that the desired numbers won't be starting with `0`.

#### [Please see the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/BQwNYX/1/)

#### [Reference](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_additional.htm)

Comment: Emma, thanks for your answer.  Are you using four dots as wildcards?  Actually some desired numbers do start with a zero, maybe even two, but the number '00000' is never desired.

Comment: It appears that this solution does not work for a number of reasons, mainly that some desired numbers begin with one or two zeros.